# JS : CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

For higher input it not works it gives fatal error : CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory what i do for running the same 
algorithm (that means using the recursion) and it successfully runs not gives the heap out of memory

```
/*CREATE THE ALL POSSIBLE PERMUTATION OF STRING.*/
var counter = 0;

function permutation(str, start, end) {
if (start === end) {
    counter++;
    console.log(str + "---" + counter);
}
else
    for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
        str = swap(str, start, i);
        permutation(str, start + 1, end);
    }
 }

/**
 * swaps the two chars of a particular string 
 */
function swap(str, swapTo, swapWith) {

let swapToChar = str[swapTo];
let swapWithChar = str[swapWith];
let result = "";
for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    let newLetterToAppend = str[i];
    if (i == swapTo)
        newLetterToAppend = swapWithChar;
    else if (i == swapWith)
        newLetterToAppend = swapToChar;
    result = result + "" + newLetterToAppend;
}

return result;
}

let str = "%4546  dfvbgjb    ";
permutation(str, 0, str.length);
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: what i do for running the same algorithm for higher input??

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37580979/149436